# How to delay a component from rendering before it gets its data

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux

I have a table component that has a search feature within a ToolkitProvider(see Below)

When I add the search prop to ToolkitProvider, my reducer returns the original state as an empty object. When I remove the search from the ToolkitProvider my reducer returns the array of objects needed for the search to work properly. I was thinking maybe conditionally render the toolkitProvider but that didn't seem to work for me. Is there a way to force the ToolkitProvider to wait until data is available before it can use its search feature?
I am using react-bootstrap-table-next

Again, when search is added to Toolkit Provider, my reducer returns an empty object  that looks like { group: { } } , this gives me "data is of type object, expected array error" If I remove the search and console.log(groupDetails) It gives me the array of objects and the table works fine, Add search get empty object, remove search get array of objects.

Here is my reducer for groupDetails

```
import { GROUP_DETAILS_REQUEST, GROUP_DETAILS_FAIL, GROUP_DETAILS_SUCCESS } from "../actions/types"

export default function groupDetailsReducer ( state = { group: {} }, action ) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GROUP_DETAILS_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true }
        case GROUP_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
            return action.payload.data.contacts
        case GROUP_DETAILS_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload}
            default:
                return state
    }
}
```

Here is the backend userCtrl function being called

```
 const groupById = async (req, res) => {
            
                try {
                    let group = await Group.findById(req.params.id).select('contacts').populate('contacts')
                    if(!group)
                    return res.status(400).json({error: "Group not found"})
         
                    res.json(group)
                    
                } catch(err) {
                    return res.status('400').json({
                        error: 'could not retrieve user'
                    })
                }
            }
```

Here is the frontend component using react-bootstrap-table-next

ITs large.... ToolkitProvider is near the bottom

```
import React, { createRef, useEffect, Fragment, useState, Suspense } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  ButtonGroup,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  Col,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownToggle,
  Media,
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
  ModalHeader,
  Row,
  UncontrolledDropdown
} from 'reactstrap';
import FalconCardHeader from '../common/FalconCardHeader';
import ButtonIcon from '../common/ButtonIcon';
import paginationFactory, { PaginationProvider } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';
import { FontAwesomeIcon , faSms} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Flex from '../common/Flex';
import Avatar from '../common/Avatar';
import { getPaginationArray } from '../../helpers/utils';

import GroupContactChoose from './GroupContactChoose'
import { deleteGroup, deleteContact, groupById } from '../../actions/index';

const GroupEdit = ({match}) => {


const GroupId = match.params.id
  let table = createRef();
  
  const { SearchBar } = Search;

  const [showContactModal, setShowContactModal ] = useState(false);
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
   

  const groupDetails = useSelector((state) => state.groupDetails)
  const { success: successGet } = groupDetails


  const CustomTotal = ({ sizePerPage, totalSize, page, lastIndex }) => (
    <span>
      {(page - 1) * sizePerPage + 1} to {lastIndex > totalSize ? totalSize : lastIndex} of {totalSize} —{' '}
    </span>
  );

  const handleDeleteGroup = (_id) => {
   
    if(window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
  dispatch(deleteGroup(_id))}
  
  }

  const firstNameFormatter = (dataField, {_id, avatar, firstName}) => {
  
    return (
    
      <Link to={`/dashboard/contact/${_id}`}>
        <Media tag={Flex} align="center">
          <Avatar name={firstName} {...avatar} />
          <Media body className="ml-2">
            <h5 className="mb-0 fs--1">{firstName}</h5>
          </Media>
        </Media>
      </Link>
    );
  };
  
  const lastNameFormatter = (dataField, { _id, lastName }) => {
    return (
      <Link to={`/dashboard/contact/${_id}`}>
        <Media tag={Flex} align="center">
          <Media body className="ml-2">
            <h5 className="mb-0 fs--1">{lastName}</h5>
          </Media>
        </Media>
      </Link>
    );
  };

  
  const actionFormatter = (dataField, { _id }, row) => (
    // Control your row with this id
    <UncontrolledDropdown>
      <DropdownMenu right className="border py-2">
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => console.log('Edit: ', _id)}>Edit</DropdownItem> 
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => { handleDeleteGroup(_id)} } className="text-danger">
          Delete
        </DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </UncontrolledDropdown>
  );
  
  

const columns = [
  {
    dataField: 'firstName',
    text: 'First Name',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: firstNameFormatter,
    sort: true
  },
 {
   dataField: 'lastName',
   text: 'Last Name',
   headerClasses: 'border-0',
   classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
   formatter: lastNameFormatter,
   sort: true
 }, 

{
  dataField: 'created',
  headerClasses: 'border-0',
  text: 'Created',
  classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
  sort: true,
  align: 'right',
  headerAlign: 'right'
},
{
  dataField: 'actions',
  headerClasses: 'border-0',
  text: 'Actions',
  classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
  formatter: actionFormatter,
  align: 'right'
}
];

const options = {
  custom: true,
  sizePerPage: 12,
  totalSize: groupDetails?.length

  useEffect(() => {
   
    dispatch(groupById(GroupId))   
  }, [successGet])
  
console.log(groupDetails)
  
  return (
    <Card className="mb-3">
      
      <FalconCardHeader title={groupDetails?.group?.data?.title} light={false}>
      
          <Fragment>
            <ButtonGroup className="mt-3">
              <ButtonIcon icon="plus" onClick={() => { setShowContactModal(true)}}transform="shrink-3 down-2" color="falcon-default" size="sm" >
              Add Contacts
            </ButtonIcon>
            <ButtonIcon icon="sms" onClick={() => { console.log(GroupId) }}transform="shrink-3 down-2" color="falcon-default" size="sm" >
              Send SMS
            </ButtonIcon>
            <ButtonIcon icon="edit" onClick={() => { setShowContactModal(true)}}transform="shrink-3 down-2" color="falcon-default" size="sm" >
              Edit
            </ButtonIcon>
            <ButtonIcon icon="trash" onClick={() => { setShowContactModal(true)}}transform="shrink-3 down-2" color="falcon-default" size="sm" >
              Delete
            </ButtonIcon>
            <Modal isOpen={showContactModal} centered toggle={() => setShowContactModal(!showContactModal)}>
            <ModalHeader className="text-center bg-light d-flex flex-between-center border-bottom-0">
                How would you like to Import?
                  </ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody className="p-0">
                        <Card>
                            <CardBody className="fs--1 font-weight-normal p-4"> 
                                <GroupContactChoose GroupId={GroupId} />
                                <Button block onClick={() => {setShowContactModal(false)}}>Close</Button>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>
            <ButtonIcon icon="external-link-alt" transform="shrink-3 down-2" color="falcon-default" size="sm">
              Export
            </ButtonIcon>
            </ButtonGroup>
          </Fragment>
        
      </FalconCardHeader>
      <CardBody className="p-0">
    
          {groupDetails.contacts ? (
            <Card>
              <CardBody>
                ...Loading // Attempting conditional rendering and having no luck..
              </CardBody> 
            </Card>
          ) : (

    
     <ToolkitProvider
           keyField="_id"
           columns={columns}
           data={groupDetails}
           bootstrap4
            // search needs to be delayed returning an empty object?
           search <---- when this is added to Toolkit Provider, my reducer returns an empty object  that looks like {group: {}} , this gives me "data is of type object, expected array error" If I remove the search and console.log(groupDetails) It gives me the array of objects and the table works fine, Add search get empty object, remove search get array of objects.
           >
             { props => (
        <PaginationProvider pagination={paginationFactory(options)}>
          {({ paginationProps, paginationTableProps }) => {
            const lastIndex = paginationProps.page * paginationProps.sizePerPage;
            return (
              <Fragment>
                <div className="table-responsive">
                <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
                  <BootstrapTable
                    ref={table}
                    selectRow={selectRow(onSelect)}
                    bordered={false}
                    classes="table-dashboard table-striped table-sm fs--1 border-bottom border-200 mb-0 table-dashboard-th-nowrap"
                    rowClasses="btn-reveal-trigger border-top border-200"
                    headerClasses="bg-200 text-900 border-y border-200"
                    {...paginationTableProps}
                    {...props.baseProps}
                  />
        
                </div>
                <Row noGutters className="px-1 py-3 flex-center">
                <Col className="pl-3 fs--1">
                <CustomTotal {...paginationProps} lastIndex={lastIndex} />
              
              </Col>

                  <Col xs="auto">
                    <Button
                      color="falcon-default"
                      size="sm"
                      onClick={handlePrevPage(paginationProps)}
                      disabled={paginationProps.page === 1}
                    >
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="chevron-left" />
                    </Button>
                    {getPaginationArray(paginationProps.totalSize, paginationProps.sizePerPage).map(pageNo => (
                      <Button
                        color={paginationProps.page === pageNo ? 'falcon-primary' : 'falcon-default'}
                        size="sm"
                        className="ml-2"
                        onClick={() => paginationProps.onPageChange(pageNo)}
                        key={pageNo}
                      >
                        {pageNo}
                      </Button>
                    ))}
                    <Button
                      color="falcon-default"
                      size="sm"
                      className="ml-2"
                      onClick={handleNextPage(paginationProps)}
                      disabled={lastIndex >= paginationProps.totalSize}
                    >
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="chevron-right" />
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Fragment>
            );
          }}
        </PaginationProvider>
         )}
         </ToolkitProvider>
)}
      </CardBody>
      
    </Card>
  )

};

export default GroupEdit
```

Comment: I tried to answer you question, but in general you should provide a minimal code example that exhibits the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you should not use `group: {}` as your default state (`state = { group: {} }`) in your reducer.

You will always get you default state initially, because redux will fire an initialization event that will not hit any of you switch cases.

If you load right away, this might be a good initial state:
`state = { group: {} }`.

Or, considering the error, an empty array might work too: `state = []`.

Comment: I tried these two changes and state = { group: { } } brought back an empty object when console.log(groupDetails)

Comment: Same with state = [], this gave me index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to `ToolkitProvider`, expected `array`.

Comment: @AmandaConda Then it's not the default value.
Impossible to say without all the code (where is `GROUP_DETAILS_SUCCESS` dispatched?), please provide a minimal example